# I want to exclude NA in my data

Tags: r, cran

I want to get mean of my data. But whenever I try to get the mean, I get a NA.

```
x=ds$age #Its my data "x"

head(x)
[1] 56 30 70 42 42  7

tail(x)
[1] 21 66 62 57 57 48

class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

Its a basic information in my data.
I want to get mean, so I use below code.

```
x <- as.numeric(x)

mean(x)
[1] NA
```

But I dont want to get NA...
Can you help me?

Comment: `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: what phiver said, but first make sure that it makes sense to have NA in your data (i.e. it doesn't come from an error in previous code), or that you shouldn't replace them by 0 etc

Answer (score 1):

You get NA because there are likely missing values in your data. E.g., in

```
 example <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 6)
```

the mean() function returns this:

```
mean(example)
[1] NA
```

You do get the mean by simply adding the argument na.rm = TRUE, thus:

```
mean(example, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The mean function has a flag you can set to remove na values.

Give this a try and see if it work.

```
mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well. I have a one more question. Why mean(x, na.rm = T) is works and why mean(ds$x,na.rm=T) is not?

Comment: @jiyoung Is there a column called x in the ds data frame?

Comment: @www No, there is no name x in a column.

Comment: So why do you think mean(ds$x,na.rm=T) is going to work if ds$x does not exist?

Comment: @jiyoung, are you meaning to try mean(ds$age,na.rm=T) instead of mean(ds$x,na.rm=T)?  That is, did you forget to replace "x" with "age" if that is the variable name in your data?